# ng2-file-upload for multipart file upload

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-file-upload, resumablejs, resume-upload

I am currently using ng2-file-upload to upload files in my application. However, I noticed that ng2-file-upload sends a multipart upload as a single part, which creates issues when uploading larger files as I lose the benefits of multipart uploads. After researching this issue, it seems that this is how ng2-file-upload is implemented. Is there a way to configure ng2-file-upload to perform file chunking, or should I consider using a different library for this functionality? Any sample references on how to do this with ng2-file-upload would be greatly appreciated.I have done some customization to ng2-file-upload and I need the queue functionality, so switching from ng2-file-upload will require a lot of work for me. Is there a way to configure ng2-file-upload to perform file chunking while retaining the queue functionality? Any sample references on how to do this with ng2-file-upload would be greatly appreciated.